# Save Excel file as CSV without truncating the values in Text format

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, export-to-csv

I have an Excel file with some long ID values in **Text** format (e.g. 8888877777569564931). When I save the Excel file as CSV, those values are truncated: the last 4 digits are replaced with 0 (e.g. 8888877777569560000).

Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/last-digits-changed-to-zeros

Comment: Excel can't save numbers with more than 15 digit as numbers. You sure the large numbers are written inside quotes?

Comment: I have already formatted that column as Text (by changing the format directly, not by adding quote), so those numbers are in Text format. But still, when the file is saved as CSV, the values are truncated..

Comment: What makes you think the long numbers are being converted when you **save** the file? Have you examined the csv file (after the very  **first** save) with a text editor like Notepad++ or Notepad?  Or are you just re-opening the file in Excel? If the latter, you must **import** the csv file, and designate the relevant column as text using either Power Query or the legacy text import wizard. Otherwise, Excel will convert the long digit string in the csv file to a number within Excel's precision limit.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld oh you are right! I opened the file in Text notebook and the format is correct. Thanks